# How to write XML with "usual" self-closing/header tags?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, formatting

This is my code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom as md
doc  = md.parse('file.props')

# operations with doc

xml_file = open('file.props', "w")
doc.writexml(xml_file, encoding="utf-8")
xml_file.close()
```

I parse an XML, I do some operations, than I open and write on it. But for example, if in my file got:

```
<MY_TAG />
       ^
```

it rewrites as:

```
<MY_TAG/>
       ^
```

I know this can seem irrelevant, but my file is constantly monitored by version control GIT, which say that line is "different" on every write.

The same with the header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

it becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

Which is pretty annoying. Any clues?

Comment: A parser is not required to maintain local 'formatting;. Equally valid ways to write that tag are `< MY_TAG />` and even `<  MY_TAG  /  >` ...

Answer (score 1):

Retaining quirks of formatting in XML through parsing and serialization is pretty well impossible. If you need to do text-level comparisons, the only way to do it is to canonicalize the formats that you are comparing (there are various XML canonicalization tools out there).

In principle you can configure git to use an XML-aware diff tool for comparisons, but please don't ask me for details, it's not something I've ever done myself. I've always just lived with the fact that it works badly.